# Cannot turn on keyboard and trackpad on 2-in-1 Win10 computer

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, touchpad, windows-tabletpc

### Background

I have a Medion MD 60250 convertible 2-in-1 touchscreen notebook/tablet with Windows 10 that has worked fine for a long time. I almost never use tablet mode (with keyboard folded to the back), occasionally use the touchscreen, and mostly use it as a notebook (with or without an external mouse; never an external keyboard).

### The problem

A few days ago, most likely after I had used the keyboard incoherently in the half-dark, the keyboard and trackpad suddenly stopped working and I cannot get them back to work since then.

### What I have investigated so far

- "not working" means absolutely **zero reaction** from any trackpad touching or clicking and from any keyboard key or key combination I could think of, including function keys such as sleep, brighter/darker, trackpad on/off, num lock, ctrl-alt-del, etc.
- The keyboard **hardware** is working OK: In BIOS, it works as expected. My problem must be a software thing at Windows level.
- I have tried turning Win10 **tablet mode on and off manually**, with or without the keyboard folded to the back, and with changing keyboard folding while in or while not in tablet mode. It had no observable effect on keyboard function or trackpad function.
- **Tablet mode** does not turn on or off **automatically** when I foldback the keyboard or un-foldback it. (Not sure if it ever did.) This holds even when I do the following:
- Win10 **tablet mode configuration** has two relevant-looking settings: ((1)) Whether (or not or as-appropriate-for-the-HW) to use tablet mode after login; ((2)) When the HW is used as a tablet: Never use tablet mode, always use it, or ask. I have played around with these with no observable effect.
- I have tried **deleting** all four **keyboard devices** in device manager and then search for new hardware.
  No change whatsoever in behavior.
- Device manager shows **39 HID devices** (no kidding). I have not yet undertaken to understand what they mean or how they relate, assuming that the above keyboard deletion should at least bring back the keyboard function.

I do not need automatic on/off switching of keyboard or trackpad or tablet mode.
But I *do* need a keyboard and a trackpad.

Any ideas are most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The solution can be found in this German-language forum:
https://community.medion.com/t5/Notebook-Netbook/Notebook-E2228T-MD-60250-MSN-30022190-Tastatur-geht-nicht-mehr/td-p/104261

It says:

1. The problem is due to a broken driver update.
   Delete a particular one of those 39 HID devices in Device Manager:
   Intel HID Event Filter
2. Let Device Manager search for new hardware, so that the device is re-created
3. Reboot

Worked for me. (Although I do not understand why the resulting state should be different from the broken previous one.)